# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException : getting this thread

Tags: objective-c

2016-02-09 11:25:11.773 TableView[1408:94586] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[**NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c5fe65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001116d6deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c0e395 -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:] + 101
    3   TableView                           0x000000010f949046 -[FlightDetailsViewController loadInfoToEdit] + 310
    4   TableView                           0x000000010f94887d -[FlightDetailsViewController viewDidLoad] + 509
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000110348f98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
    6   UIKit                               0x000000011034ef4f -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 120
    7   UIKit                               0x000000011037ee44 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1203
    8   UIKit                               0x000000011038f23f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001103903af -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000110536ff7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001102694a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000011507759a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000011506be70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000011506bcee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000115060475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000011508dc0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001101ddb47 _afterCACommitHandler + 174
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b8b367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b8b2d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b80f2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b80828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000114b2aad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001101b2610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    24  TableView                           0x000000010f94855f main + 111
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001126f292d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: check your array count.

Comment: Your NSArray is empty.

Comment: that is the problem you are getting exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned (and your output clearly states) your NSArray is empty. If you attempt to reference an index from an NSArray that does not exist it will crash every time.

Apparently you are attempting to access an object at index 0. You can error check that the array has at least the number of items as the index number as such:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"foo"];

int indexDesired = 0; //since you were attempting to access index 0
long indexCount = [myArray count];

if (indexCount > indexDesired) { //check to make sure index exists
    id myObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexDesired];
}
```